# How to use a text file as standard input to test my program in XCode 4.33

Tags: xcode

I'm having trouble figuring out how to test my program using XCode.  I usually edit in the command line with vim, but am trying to transition to an IDE.  I'm sure there is an easy way to do the equivalent of `homework.out < testfile.txt`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but putting "< testfile.txt" in the scheme's command line arguments may work. Apparently doing something similar worked for an earlier version of Xcode.